# Different Div Alignments on Different Resolution

Tags: html, css, stack, resolution

http://codepen.io/jiselllla/pen/MJzRjV

I've put a codepen to help with what I'm trying to do.
For starters, I didn't hardcode this site, I did it in Webflow which is some interactive interface to build a website, then I extracted the HTML code. Of course it's not ideal... but anyway, here I am.

The dropdowns under 'Africa' stack when the screen resolution changes, and the dropdowns under 'Asia' don't (the ones I'm trying to code to stack @ different res). The former are input in by Webflow's 'dropdown' widget, but I find them very burdensome and want to just hardcode mine in manually. I've tried a while to try to mimic the code for the dropdowns under Africa (something to do with the @media bit?) but for some reason, no matter how hard I try, I can't get them to stack. Can someone offer a solution?

```
.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Bitter, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tweaked your original pen and created [my own](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZGKmV/). What I changed:

- I gave the dropdowns a container with a class of `dropdown-container` that can control how they are organized as the screen size changes.
- I added a `display: flex` CSS property to the `dropdown-container` class. And I set `flex-flow: column` to tell the container to order these elements in a single column.
- When the screen goes below 750px, I change the `flex-flow` property on the container to `row` so that the dropdowns are then organized in a single row.

If you don't know much about flexbox, [this is the cheat sheet I always fall back on](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Thanks so much for this, will take a look at the flexbox sheet you gave. Such a simple fix..

Comment: glad it worked out for you. Now mark my answer as correct so I can have those sweet internet points :)

Comment: Hello again, since there's no way for private message, is there any possibility you can help me out with one more thing re: image rotation? I've attached another codepen: http://codepen.io/jiselllla/pen/yMYwOr

I don't wanna ask another 'image rotation' qn. Problem is, when I rotate the image (guy in front of Christmas Tree), the alignment does not fall into place. Any solution given the codepen? (CSS code for rotate image is on top, since extracted from Webflow I've tried to copy the original image code and just add rotation. It does rotate, but the alignment is off)